# How do I prevent users from sharing the same account? (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, security

I have a subscription based website (with a monthly fee) and I would like to prevent users from sharing accounts in order to avoid paying the monthly fee.

Is there a way this can be done?

Cheers,

Mike

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The approach with IP is not suitable, because there are users that use the same external ip in order to surf the web. But in some cases it's a suitable approach(let's say in an intranet web application for example).
You can monitor the number of concurent sessions for the same login. Than one approach would be to log when more than 1 concurent session is present for the same login. Than you may analyse the logs.
Base on these data you may take some actions. good luck.

Comment: Multiple users on the same machine would not work because they don't share cookies.  So if the session is cookie based then that would not work.

Answer (score 2):

Keep a log of the IP adresses of the account. If it changes quickly and oftenly I think it is safe to assume that the account is used by multiple people.

Comment: I thought most people get allocated a new IP each time they connect through their provider. I don't think this approach will be a good indication of unique users.

Comment: @Paul: Your assumption is correct. Our DSL line works that way.

Comment: I like the log idea too. Prevention it is not, but if the user can see that you've logged each login with their IP and geolocation (see http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/geolite for that idea), then that log shows them that you are onto their theft of your services.  You have evidence of the theft and can act to disable the account or at least launch an investigation.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way of doing this for definite.  However, you could add a layer of authentication on top to ask them some form of security questions like date of birth, place of birth, etc.

I would be more reluctant on giving a bunch of people this information!

Comment: Also dont allow multiple sessions of login, implementing it in the authentication layer!

Comment: I would also be reluctant to give this information to a random website.

Answer (score 1):

You're pretty much out of luck here, unfortunately. The only potential route you could take here would be checking IP addresses, but this is extremely unreliable for this mechanism.

Comment: Right.  Obviously, you could say "You may only use the server from one IP."  This will defeat most account sharing but also piss off a large group of legitimate users.

Comment: Why not store details of currently active or logged in users. As they login create a record. As they logout create another record. Then if multiple accounts are still logged in.. Deny them.. If a session stays logged in and they don't logout properly you could use some time based calculation to see if that logged in user perhaps has actually is logged out.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to stop multiple people using the same account at the same time or at different times?

You can stop the former by storing a GUID in a user's session and checking it against a value you've set in a cookie. No problem.

You just can't reliably stop the latter. Storing the IP will work to some extent, but most home users are allocated a new IP frequently (as previously stated by another comment). You could use an IP -> Location and check if the location varies frequently.

Unfortunately, savvy users will use a proxy server to defeat this mechanism too.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't heard of someone doing that, so we'll have to think and come up with something.

Log the IP address with account id and activity timestamp. Look for a web service which tells you where that IP is from. Look for connections from the same account on different IPs.

For example, if I have 2 concurrent sessions on the same IP, you can't be sure. Maybe I have Firefox and Chrome open at the same time.

If I have 2 concurrent sessions with different IPs, then you're positive I'm sharing accounts (if this happens often).

If I use, throughout the week, several different IPs, you can't tell, because I'm allowed to use different computers, or use my friends' internet connection when I'm visiting. Even if the IPs are on different countries.

So, I would suggest logging the IP addresses, look for a location service, and test rules written from live data.